# How can I pass a Boolean Array or Unsigned Char* to cout?

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, air

I'm passing an array of 76800 Booleans (could be integers or unsigned char* instead) to Actionscript (AIR). The best solution I've come up with so far is to launch my C++ app as a NativeProcess, which gives my AIR app access to stdout.

My solution is sort of working, but I feel it's a terrible hack, and I don't understand ostream well enough to know how else to pass things:

```
// Variables
stringstream ss;
int arrayLength = 76800;

// Put data into stringstream
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i){
    ss << data[i];
}

// Convert stringstream to stream
string message;
ss >> message;

// Send Data
cout << message;
```

Is there a way to output these values in one big block without turning them into a string?

Edit: in AS3, I'd ideally cast this incoming data as a [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) so that I can use it as BitmapData.

Performance is the issue, here - this is essentially a 2-bit image I'm trying to pass to as3, so this all needs to happen 15-30 times per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first pass, why bother putting them into a stream only to convert that to a string and write that to a stream?  Just do it in one pass:

```
int arrayLength = 76800;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    cout << data[i];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger output 76800 times, though? My as3 app will try to read the data whenever cout is used, and as3 is slooooow compared to c++, so I'd rather only call my as3 ingestion function once.

Comment: Try it.  stdio has buffering.

Comment: Hmmm - seems like it's always outputting 4096 values. So it's buffering, but I'd have to do some logic on the as3 end to patch it back together.

Comment: Probably BUFSIZ is 4096 on your system.  How about just sending the number of bools first, then the data itself?  Then the receiving end will know to keep reading until it gets all the values.  If this doesn't work, I think it may imply something deeper is wrong with your design.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. In this case, the number of bools will always be the same (all the pixels in a 320x240 image, on or off). It sounds like my original hope of sending the data as one big chunk may not be possible, which is not ideal, but workable if it's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `boolalpha` flag, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    cout << boolalpha << data[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, hadn't run across boolalpha, thanks! However, I need to output all of the data at once so I can ingest it within as3 in one big chunk, rather than accepting 76800 booleans one by one.

Comment: This is not useful--outputting each bool as one character is more efficient than 4-5 characters plus a newline for each.

Comment: Right, 0/1 is more compact than 'true'/'false', but it's a handy tip for a c++ n00b :)

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Since `stdout` is intended for text, your solution is probably the best. The only other alternative, is to see if you can set `stdout` to binary mode, but this is not standard, so you have to consult the compiler you are using.

Comment: Hm - I'm using Visual C++. Looks like I can try:
`_setmode(1, _O_BINARY)`
to turn on Binary mode, then
`cout.write(data, 76800);`
to send it out. I'll have to give this a go tomorrow.